# State setter throwing TypeError: not a function React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, typeerror

I have this async function where I'm fetching data for each item in the input array. I would like to update the state with new data every time new data is fetched with the API.

I defined the state hook in a different component and then passed the `setObjID` function as an argument to this current component.

The code snippet:

```js
const fetchPromises = objectIDs.map(async (objectID) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${objEndpoint}${objectID}`);
  return response.json();
})

try {
  const responses = await Promise.all(fetchPromises);

  setObjID(responses); // this line doesn't work
  console.log(responses);
}
```

The console is not logging anything, even if I hardcode a value. And the error is this:

```bash
TypeError: setObjID is not a function
    at getData
```

I need to be able to dynamically update this data because then I have to pass it into various UI elements that will change based on the user input, and therefore, the data that gets fetched. Everything else works fine, it's just this line that's giving me a serious headache.

Any ideas?

I tried everything I could think of and ChatGPT just kept telling me to ensure I was passing the function correctly to the component, which I am, so I am at a loss right now.

Comment: Please share the code where `setObjID` is defined and passed to your component.

Comment: export default function Trial() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null); 
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [objID, setObjID] = useState([]);

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code, do not put it in comment. Also include the part where you pass the prop.

Comment: Can you try `return await response.json()` in your return statement in the map method?

Comment: @i2i3 not sure what that is supposed to do but it didn't change the error message nor anything else :(

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call the function using the props."property" notation, like so:

```
props.setObjID();
```

This assumes that the name of the prop you passed to the component is named the same as `setObjID`, like this:

```
<Component setObjID={setObjID} />
```

If you haven't destructured the prop in the component's arguments, then you'll need to use this approach. You can code it like this in the component file:

```
function Component(props) {
  /* Component content here */
}
```

Thusly allowing you to use the `props.setObjID();` notation to access the setter function.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, when I do that, I just get another TypeError: props.setData is not a function
    at getData

Comment: I'm guessing the property you passed to the component is: setData={setObjID}? Which is why you are attempting to use props.setData here? It basically looks like there is either a spelling error somewhere, which is meaning the function isn't actually being accessed, or there is some sort of scope issue which doesn't allow the function to be read from where you are trying to call it.

Comment: Ah I have just seen from another of your comments that setData() is part of another state hook. This would suggest that you are now getting a new error - the suggestion would be that you haven't passed setData as a prop (property), and as such you aren't currently able to access it with props.setData. Make sure it is being passed as: setData={setData} to the component.

Comment: Hm, not really. I pass it in like this: 
export default function SearchObjAPI(input, setData, setObjID)

and then use setObjID like this inside a nested async function:

const fetchPromises = objectIDs.map(async (objectID) => {
                    const response = await fetch(`${objEndpoint}${objectID}`);
                    return response.json();
                })
                try {
                    const responses = await Promise.all(fetchPromises); // waits for all promises to resolve
    
                    setObjID(responses); // this line doesn't work         }

Comment: Try adding curly brackets around `input, setData, setObjID` , like this: `SearchObjAPI({ input, setData, SetObjID })`. This will destructure the props you are passing to it and allow you to use them directly as functions.